# Certain website's url does not change after login e.g. facebook.com stays facebook.com after login?

Tags: php, .htaccess

My website URL is `www.xyz.com` after login I redirect it to home page then my URL looks like `www.xyz.com/home` but I want to stay as `www.xyz.com` even after login...

How to do it? Most of the websites like facebook, twitter does it.

How to create the access file for it?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix this can be done with standard PHP or even with Apache configuration only. No need for hyped stuff for standard web practice.

Comment: I don't want to start a discussion but you can stay on a single URL and do all you want without crazy technology. This is standard HTTP and could be even done with standard Apache configuration, you don't even need programing to do such stuff. Apache has endless possibilities to evaluate HTTP headers and alter the response without redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special trick here. Any URL can be loaded when you're logged out, and then loaded again when you're logged in.

If your application assumes that everyone who goes to `/home` is logged in, it's clearly insecure. If `/home` can tell whether the user is logged in, so can `/`.

An application can do what it likes with that information - it doesn't have to redirect to a different page if the user is in the "wrong" state, it can just serve different content.

Comment: Thank You... all I had to do was just use include_once("page.php");